# QUERIES about relationship in ERD

Tags: erd

Is it possible to have two entities linking to a weak entity?? If yes, how's the example like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are occasions where it's possible.

e.g.

You have an "Employee" entity, which has the weaker entity "Dependent" which has the weaker entity "Hobby". (Mr. Smith has a son, Daniel, who plays football)